# React Native Datadog Error Tracking is not working

Tags: android, react-native, datadog

I'm following this documentation by datadog about the configuration of error tracking https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/error_tracking/reactnative/ I ready uploaded the sourcemap successfully by using **datadog-react-native-wizard** and by running ./gradlew assembleRelease. If minifyEnabled = true the app is crashing, there's no log or any sign what is the cause of the crash therefore I disabled it.

Here's the successful upload of sourcemap

[image]

Even it is successful still the error is like this...

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Can you help me find what's wrong or did I miss something? I appreciate your help on this.